# Expected value of max of two discrete random variables

Tags: expected-value, conditional-expectation, order-statistics, conditioning

I'm reading this paper [An Efficient PTAS for Stochastic Load Balancing with Poisson Jobs](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2006.12670.pdf). Which is solving a [makespan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_shop_scheduling) minimizing job-shop problem for Poisson job sizes. Basically, schedule the minimum work for random job sizes whose job size distributions are Poissonian. The authors give an equation that I hadn't seen before:

$$\mathbb{E} \left[ \text{max}(X,Y) \right] = 
\sum_{x=0}^\infty \Pr\{X=x\} \left\{ x + \sum_{y=x+1}^\infty \Pr\{Y \geq y\} \right\}, $$
where $X$ and $Y$ are both random (independent) variables on support $\{0,1,\dots\}$.

I can think of one general approach (conditional expectations) that seems reasonable to derive this but I'm not able to get the result.

Can someone derive this result?

Note: I'll accept any derivation, the approach need not use conditional expectations. I only mention because it seems like this is a conditional expectation identity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $Z \in \{0,1,\dots\}$ be a nonnegative discrete random variable. Then, we have
$$
\mathbb E[ Z ]= \sum_{z = 1}^\infty \mathbb P(Z \ge z).
$$
Try to prove this yourself  <sub>--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Hint: $Z = \sum_{z=1}^\infty (\cdots)$.</sub>.

Let $Z = \max(X,Y)$. Then,
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[\max(X,Y)] &= \sum_{z=1}^\infty \mathbb P(\max(X,Y) \ge z) 
\\
&=\sum_{z=1}^\infty \sum_{x=0}^\infty \mathbb P(X = x) \mathbb P(\max(x,Y) \ge z \mid X = x) \\
&=\sum_{x=0}^\infty \mathbb P(X = x) \Big[ \sum_{z=1}^\infty  \mathbb P(\max(x,Y) \ge z)\Big] \quad \text{(by indept.)} \\
&=\sum_{x=0}^\infty \mathbb P(X = x) \Big[ x + \sum_{z=x+1}^\infty  \mathbb P(Y \ge z)\Big]. 
\end{align}

Comment: thanks, I had missed the reasoning on the line using the independence criteria.